# Magento : Replace Discontinued Product with New Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, event-observer

I making observer, that detects when someone reorders a discontinued product and *should* replace that product with a new product.

**My question is:** How do I retrieve a product object with a specific SKU? For example I want to retrieve the product with the SKU `D1105` and add that to the cart using `$observer->getEvent()->setProduct( $myDD1105Product );`.

I need to know, how to retrieve a product with the SKU `D1105` and add it to the cart. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
class MHT_Reorder_Model_Observer
{

    public function onReorder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();

        $replacementSku = 'D1105';
        $blackListSKUs = ['D1100', 'D1101'];

        foreach ($blackListSKUs as $blacklistSku) {
            // if product SKU does not equal $blacklistSku: continue iterating
            if (strcasecmp($product->getSku(), $blacklistSku) != 0)
                continue;

            // How do I get the product from Mage/database that has the sku D1105?
            $event->setProduct()
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To load any product using it sku, you need to used following code.

```
$sku = 'D1105';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','your_value'
);
```

That's it !